# Remove last item from function parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I am writing a method to extract values from arbitrarily nested structs. I am almost there, but would like to also provide an option to convert the value retrieved (by default no conversion). Since parameter packs can't be followed by another template parameter, I have to fudge this a bit. The below works except for the indicated line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} bar;

typedef struct {
    int c;
    bar d;
} baz;


template <typename T, typename S, typename... Ss>
auto inline getField(const T& obj, S field1, Ss... fields)
{
    if constexpr (!sizeof...(fields))
        return obj.*field1;
    else
        return getField(obj.*field1, fields...);
}

template <typename Obj, typename Out, class ...C, typename... T>
auto inline getFieldC(const Obj& obj, Out, T C::*... field)
{
    return static_cast<Out>(getField(obj, field...));
}

template<class T> struct tag_t { using type = T; };
template<class...Ts>
using last = typename std::tuple_element_t< sizeof...(Ts) - 1, std::tuple<tag_t<Ts>...> >::type;

template <typename Obj, typename... T>
auto getMyFieldWrapper(const Obj& obj, T... field)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_member_object_pointer_v<last<Obj, T...>>)
        return getField(obj, field...);
    else
        return getFieldC(obj, last<Obj, T...>{}, field...);  // <- this doesn't compile, need a way to pass all but last element of field
}

int main()
{
    baz myObj;
    std::cout << getMyFieldWrapper(myObj, &baz::c);              // works
    std::cout << getMyFieldWrapper(myObj, &baz::d, &bar::b);     // works
    std::cout << getMyFieldWrapper(myObj, &baz::d, &bar::b, 0.); // doesn't work
}
```

How do I implement the indicated line? I'm using the latest MSVC, and am happy to make full use of C++17 to keep things short and simple.

Comment: I rolled your edit back - don't edit answers into your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually more helpful to invert the flow. First, write a higher-order function that forwards an index sequence:

```
template <typename F, size_t... Is>
auto indices_impl(F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return f(std::integral_constant<size_t, Is>()...);
}

template <size_t N, typename F>
auto indices(F f) {
    return indices_impl(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

That is just generally useful in lots of places.

In this case, we use it to write a higher-order function to drop the last element in a pack:

```
template <typename F, typename... Ts>
auto drop_last(F f, Ts... ts) {
    return indices<sizeof...(Ts)-1>([&](auto... Is){
        auto tuple = std::make_tuple(ts...);
        return f(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
    });
}
```

And then you can use that:

```
return drop_last([&](auto... elems){
    return getMyField(obj, last<Obj, T...>{}, elems...);
}, field...);
```

References omitted for brevity.

---

Of course, if you want to combine both and just rotate, you can do:

```
// Given f and some args t0, t1, ..., tn, calls f(tn, t0, t1, ..., tn-1)
template <typename F, typename... Ts>
auto rotate_right(F f, Ts... ts) {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(ts...);
    return indices<sizeof...(Ts)-1>([&](auto... Is){
        return f(
            std::get<sizeof...(Ts)-1>(tuple),
            std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
    });
}
```

used as:

```
return rotate_right([&](auto... elems){
    return getMyField(obj, elems...);
}, field...);
```

Comment: Very cool technique! Thanks! Sadly, both don't compile on me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99cf9113ccf0570b

Comment: That was a typo in my code, fixed now. works! thanks!

Comment: The `drop_last` and `rotate_right` functions call `std::get<Is>`, but `Is` is a parameter pack containing `std::integral_constant<size_t>`, right? How does that work? I thought the first template argument to `std::get` needed to be `size_t`, not `std::integral_constant`?

Comment: Ah! I guess it's because `std::integral_constant<size_t>` has a `constexpr size_t operator()()`, so is implicitly convertible to `size_t` even in constant expressions?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I implement the indicated line?

Not sure to understand what do you want but... it seems to me that you can make it calling an intermediate function

```
template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
auto noLastArg (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &,
                std::tuple<Ts...> const & tpl)
 { return getMyField(std::get<Is>(tpl)...); }
```

you can rewrite your function as follows

```
template <typename Obj, typename ... T>
auto getMyFieldWrapper (Obj const & obj, T ... field)
 {
   if constexpr (std::is_member_object_pointer<last<Obj, T...>>::value )
      return getMyField(obj, field...);
   else
      return noLastArg(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{}, 
                       std::make_tuple(obj, field...));
 }
```

The idea is pack the arguments for `getMyField` in a `std::tuple` of `sizeof...(T)+1u` elements (+1 because there is also `obj`) and call `getMyField()` unpacking the first `sizeof...(T)` of them.

But isn't clear, to me, if you want also `last<Obj, T...>{}`.

In this case, the call to `noLastArg()` become

```
      return noLastArg(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)+1u>{}, 
                       std::make_tuple(obj, last<Obj, T...>{}, field...));
```